# Cancelling a queued file on teracopy

Tags: teracopy

This is the scenario I find myself in often:

Try to copy a very large file to a folder using teracopy. After a minute, try to copy a tiny file to the same folder.

Tera copy queues the tiny file and will not start copying it until the huge file is done. First of all, is there a solution to this?

But either way, no worries, I can copy it with with regular explorer because I want the tiny file to be done faster. But now, the tiny file is still queued on tera copy and it seems like canceling a queued transfer is a premium feature that I need to pay for? It seems absurd that such a key feature as "cancel" requires payment so I am hoping I was just too dumb to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you use TeraCopy, it will add small transfers to the current queue, and for large transfers it creates a new queue. I'm not entirely sure if this is a behavior of version 3 only though. Could be that you need version 3 for this.

Anyway, the solution is simple, press the + button on the bottom left to create a new transfer first, and either use that window to transfer your small files or see if windows automatically uses that window when you create a copy. Once the second window is there, you can either have both copy at the same time, or pause the first, copy the second, then resume the first.

To remove the existing item from the first task without a license (I bought it long time ago, its definitely worth the small price) you could use task manager to kill the process, then create a new transfer for that big file and hope that it can resume, or just let it in the queue. The file is copied anyway, so the only thing that will happen, is that it gets copied a second time.